# An efficient Postgres query to get last 10 rows of a large table

Tags: postgresql

I have a large postgres table of 10 million rows. I am looking for a SQL query to fetch the last 10 rows of the table. Currently I am using ORDER BY clause as follows

```
Select * from Guests
ORDER BY number desc 
LIMIT 10
```

But the query is super slow. When I enable the timing parameter, it yields 1 second.

Is it possible to improve the query?

Optimizations applied so far:

1. I have an index set up on the column    ‘number’.
2. I have tried to modify the query to fetch the last record using offset. But I get the results in Ascending order and then I have to sort it which is still slow.

Is it possible to improve upon these results?

Comment: Your index should be sufficient to get an efficient plan (if it is a default btree index). Show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query, preferably with track_io_timing turned on.